# Why many empty revisions are created via JSON:API?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm a D9.5.x site.

I've a content type with content moderation and content translation enabled and configured.
That content type has also a paragraph field.
Despite this kind of setup not being officially "stable", it worked fine for almost 2 years.

However, recently we had to implement the creation and editing of that content type via a javascript editor. We used json:api for the api.

This also works in most cases.

However, for some nodes the revisions\moderation get inconsistent states.
For example, a node is sent to "review" with some new field values. When it is published - using Drupal interface, not json:api - the old values are published instead of the newest.
Those fields with inconsistent values are usually the one with "relationship". e.g. images.

I can't replicate clearly of why or when this happens - it's a minimum percentage of 5000+ nodes what shows problems, while in most cases seems to work.

So far, I could only see that the nodes with "problems" have a lot of empty pages under revisions tab  [image]

Anyone has ever encounter a problem like this?